# Replace #Ref over within several Ranges

Tags: excel, vba

New to coding so sorry if I'm completely ignoring contexts as I'm still trying to learn them.

I have cells that are trying to pull data from several Pivot Tables in another worksheet. If it is unable to pull any information from the pivot tables, it will return #REF. The Macro is supposed to search through in each cell within several ranges to search for the #REF and replace it with a 0. The reason its several ranges instead of the entire worksheet is that some of the equations are trying to add values from a table and since some of those values are #REF, the sum also ends up being #REF. I need to keep those equations there so once the #REF's are replaced, they would get the sum.

```
    Dim Areas(13) As Range
    Set Areas(1) = Range("C5:Z7")
    Set Areas(2) = Range("C10:Z14")
    Set Areas(3) = Range("C27:Z27")
    Set Areas(4) = Range("C33:Z45")
    Set Areas(5) = Range("C52:Z55")
    Set Areas(6) = Range("C58:Z61")
    Set Areas(7) = Range("C63:Z66")
    Set Areas(8) = Range("C68:Z72")
    Set Areas(9) = Range("C74:Z78")
    Set Areas(10) = Range("C80:Z84")
    Set Areas(11) = Range("C86:Z90")
    Set Areas(12) = Range("C92:Z96")
    Set Areas(13) = Range("C102:Z112")

    For R = 1 To 13
        For Each cell In Areas(R)            'Error: For Each may only iterate over a collection object 
            If cell.Value = CVErr(xlErrName) Then
                .Replace What:="#REF!", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
            Else
        Next
```

I made a bunch of notes after my code to try to work off of based on other StackOverflow questions which I listed below. I figured they worked will form a single range but I'm working with several. **If none of what I did makes sense then disregard the below and help me start over. (Please?)** Let me know if you need any more information.

```
    If IsError(cell.Value) Then
'    If cell.Value = CVErr(xlErrName) Then
'        ...
'    End If
'End If

'Dim nm As Name
'    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
'        If InStr(nm.Value, "#REF!") > 0 Then
'            nm.Delete
'    End If
    'Next nm

'    ActiveCell.Replace What:="#REF!", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, _
'        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
'        ReplaceFormat:=False

'With Range("B11:AP55").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
'    .Formula = Replace(.Formula, "#REF", "Master", , , vbTextCompare)
'End With
```

Comment: `Areas` shouldn't be a `String`. for starters.

Comment: Declare the `Areas` array `As Range`, and `Set` its items; the `For Each` loop will work then, and each element will be a full-fledged `Range` object.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Ok so I made some edits to my original post. Does that look a little more accurate to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Probably - but I doubt you're still getting that error on `For Each` though. That said you're not iterating cells, you're iterating *ranges* of cells - you'll need to nest that loop in order to iterate each cell in each range, because `cell.Value` is a 2D variant array now - that makes `If cell.Value = CVErr(xlErrName) Then` illegal.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `xlErrRef` rather than `xlErrName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to `Find`, consider `SpecialCells`

To remove *only* `#REF` errors

```
Sub Demo1()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rErr As Range
    Dim cl As Range

    With ActiveSheet 'or specify a specific sheet
        Set rng = .Range("C5:Z7,C10:Z14,C27:Z27,C33:Z45,C52:Z55,C58:Z61,C63:Z66,C68:Z72,C74:Z78,C80:Z84,C86:Z90,C92:Z96,C102:Z112")
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rErr = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rErr Is Nothing Then
        For Each cl In rErr.Cells
            If cl.Value = CVErr(xlErrRef) Then
                cl.Offset(0, 1) = 0
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

To remove *All* errors:

```
Sub Demo2()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rErr As Range

    With ActiveSheet 'or specify a specific sheet
        Set rng = .Range("C5:Z7,C10:Z14,C27:Z27,C33:Z45,C52:Z55,C58:Z61,C63:Z66,C68:Z72,C74:Z78,C80:Z84,C86:Z90,C92:Z96,C102:Z112")
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rErr = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rErr Is Nothing Then
        rErr = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The first code would receive an error after then first loop but the second code worked B.E.A.utifully